# How to add and retrieve values from mongoDB to react drag and drop

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mern, react-beautiful-dnd

I am a beginner for learning MERN stack. I have developed a simple todo app in react using react-beautiful-dnd. However, I am not sure on how to retrieve data from mongoDB to the specific todo list columns, such as "todo" , 'inprogress" and completed column.

How I should retrieve data from mongoDB to the specific droppable column? I am familiar in retrieving data, but do no have any idea on how to retrieve to the specific column. Further, are there any specifications to be met to retrieve data in this way, when adding data to mongoDB?

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {DragDropContext, Droppable, Draggable} from "react-beautiful-dnd";
import _ from "lodash";
import {v4} from "uuid";

const item = {
  id: v4(),
  name: "Clean the house"
}

const item2 = {
  id: v4(),
  name: "Wash the car"
}

function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("")
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    //creating 3 columns
    "todo": {
      title: "Todo",
      items: [item, item2]//temporary data valuesa
    },
    "in-progress": {
      title: "In Progress",
      items: []
    },
    "done": {
      title: "Completed",
      items: []
    }
  })

  const handleDragEnd = ({destination, source}) => {
    if (!destination) {
      return
    }

    if (destination.index === source.index && destination.droppableId === source.droppableId) {
      return
    }

    // Creating a copy of item before removing it from state
    const itemCopy = {...state[source.droppableId].items[source.index]}

    setState(prev => {
      prev = {...prev}
      // Remove from previous items array
      prev[source.droppableId].items.splice(source.index, 1)


      // Adding to new items array location
      prev[destination.droppableId].items.splice(destination.index, 0, itemCopy)

      return prev
    })
  }

  const addItem = () => {
    setState(prev => {
      return {
        ...prev,
        todo: {
          title: "Todo",
          items: [
            {
              id: v4(),
              name: text
            },
            ...prev.todo.items
          ]
        }
      }
    })

    setText("")
  }
  //the dragdropcontext is the wrapper for draging elements
  //dropable is the certain area inside the column where u can drop items
  //dragble are the items in the column to be dragged



  //here {_.map(state, (data, key) => { 
    //the above function is used to return the data and key of all 3 elements mentioned under use state() above
    //the key: returns todo,inprogress,and done
    //where as the data returns all the values of the variables within each key
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <input type="text" value={text} onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}/>
        <button onClick={addItem}>Add</button>
      </div>
      <DragDropContext onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}>
   
        {_.map(state, (data, key) => {
          return(
            <div key={key} className={"column"}>
              <h3>{data.title}</h3>
              <Droppable droppableId={key}>
                {(provided, snapshot) => {
                  return(
                    <div
                      ref={provided.innerRef}
                      {...provided.droppableProps}
                      key = {"Todo"}
                      className={"droppable-col"}
                    >
                      {data.items.map((el, index) => {
                        return(
                          <Draggable key={el.id} index={index} draggableId={el.id}>
                            {(provided, snapshot) => {
                              console.log(snapshot)
                              return(
                                <div
                                  className={`item ${snapshot.isDragging && "dragging"}`}
                                  ref={provided.innerRef}
                                  {...provided.draggableProps}
                                  {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                                >
                                  {el.name}
                                </div>
                              )
                            }}
                          </Draggable>
                        )
                      })}
                      {provided.placeholder}
                    </div>
                  )
                }}
              </Droppable>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </DragDropContext>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```